# Partially update a document without removing missing fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I'd like to index the document

```
PUT twitter/_doc/1
{
    "user" : "kimchy",
    "any" : "thing"
}
GET twitter/_doc/1
```

which returns

```
{
  "_index": "twitter",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 3,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "user": "kimchy",
    "any": "thing"
  }
}
```

but then I'd like to update the document (without completely overwriting the original one) [notice the difference in fields]

```
PUT twitter/_doc/1
{
    "user" : "kimchy",
    "some" : "thing"
}
GET twitter/_doc/1

{
  "_index": "twitter",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 6,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "user": "kimchy",
    "some": "thing"
  }
}
```

but ES overwrites the whole document. Is there any way to leave missing fields untouched?

Ideally, I'd like to get

```
  "_source": {
    "user": "kimchy",
    "any" : "thing",
    "some": "thing"
  }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to do a [partial update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_updates_with_a_partial_document), like this

```
POST twitter/_doc/1/_update
{
  "doc": {
    "user" : "kimchy",
    "some" : "thing"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to make it work as a regular `index` operation (upsert)?

Comment: No, an index operation will always replace the document